# Bootstrap Modal Not Firing Properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am programmatically firing a Bootstrap modal (as opposed to firing with data-toggle="modal") and it doesn't display in Safari. Note that I have looked at other questions on SO, but they focus on the data attribute invocation.

I essentially have a link that links out to an external page. This external page takes some time to load, so I've created a modal to use as an activity indicator.

Note that the setTimeout function is just to delay the transition to the external page for the sake of example since I am unable to link to the actual page.

**ISSUE**

When you click on the "Click to Fire Modal" link in Safari, the modal doesn't display. It does display in other modern browsers.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Loader Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loader-modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loaderlabel">
  <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm vertical-align-center">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header custom">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="loadingSpinner"><div class="spinner-wave"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div><span class="text-center"><b>Loading Pallet...</b></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Loader Modal -->

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="#" class="btn-openOrd">
        <h4 class="pghead">Click to Fire Modal</h4>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.loadingSpinner, .loadingSpinnerKit {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
}
p.loadingSpinner.big {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.spinner-wave {
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.spinner-wave-med {
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.spinner-wave-big {
    margin: 0 auto 5px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.spinner-wave-med>div, .spinner-wave>div {
    background-color: #E11937;
    height: 100%;
    width: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: wave 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: wave 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.spinner-wave-big>div {
    background-color: #E11937;
    height: 100%;
    width: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: wave 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: wave 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.spinner-wave div:nth-child(2), .spinner-wave-med div:nth-child(2), .spinner-wave-big div:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
    animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.spinner-wave div:nth-child(3), .spinner-wave-med div:nth-child(3), .spinner-wave-big div:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
    animation-delay: -1s;
}
.spinner-wave div:nth-child(4), .spinner-wave-med div:nth-child(4), .spinner-wave-big div:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -.9s;
    animation-delay: -.9s;
}
.spinner-wave div:nth-child(5), .spinner-wave-med div:nth-child(5), .spinner-wave-big div:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -.8s;
    animation-delay: -.8s;
    margin-right: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes wave {
    0%, 40%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
    }
}
@keyframes wave {
    0%, 40%, 100% {
        transform: scaleY(0.4);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scaleY(1.0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
    }
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn-openOrd').on('click', function() {
        var loaderModal = $('#loader-modal');
        loaderModal.find('.modal-body').html('<div class="loadingSpinner"><div class="spinner-wave"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div><span class="text-center"><b>Loading Orders & Quotes...</b></span></div>');
        loaderModal.modal('show');
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = 'https://jquery.com/';
        }, 8000);
});
```

I created a Fiddle to see what I'm doing. Note that this works in other modern browsers - just not Safari.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coryspi/eh0wnctq/3/)

Comment: 1. The jsfiddle doesn't have the same code as you posted here. 2. In chrome it doesn't work. 3. What **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: @Dekel, I updated the Fiddle as appropriate. I also updated the issue description above. Essentially, in Safari, the modal doesn't display when you click the" Click to Fire Modal" button. It does display in other browsers.

Comment: Now it's clear (and work). Which version of safari?

Comment: I just checked it in safari and everything there works. Are you sure?

Comment: Ok, interesting. I was testing in Safari 9.1 & 10. It does work when I isolate this code. Unfortunately, this code is intertwined with a lot of other code to the point where creating an example for SO would not be feasible. I guess I now know that the REAL issue is elsewhere. Thanks for your help in understanding that, Dekel.

Comment: Check the console for errors. If you get javascript errors the `link` will just open (without the modal).

Comment: I don't remember seeing errors, but the link did just open. I'll have another look, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome @dentalhero :)

Comment: Will do, Dekel, thanks.

Comment: Wht do you mean by SO? is it software optimization? if it is then your code can be easily optimize by not writing the hole model your self. And just letting it write at run time by some other JS. This will reduce your code and efforts also and gives you ability to manage multiple level of bootstrap easily. If you want further help comment here.

Comment: Hi Shalin, thanks, I was actually just referring to Stack Overflow with the "SO" acronmyn.